# Spring Cloud Data Flow Stream Deployment to Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am new to spring cloud data flow. I am trying to build a simple http source and rabbitmq sink stream using SCDF stream app.The stream should be deployed on OSCF (Cloud Foundry). Once deployed, the stream should be able to receive HTTP POST Request and send the request data to RabbitMQ.

So far, I have downloaded Data Flow Server using below link and push to cloud foundry. I am using Shall application from my local.

https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/cloudfoundry/cf-cli/.

I also have HTTP Source and RabbitMQ Sink application which is deployed in CF. RabbitMQ service is also bound to sink application.

My question - how can I create a stream using application deployed in CF? Registering app requires HTTP/File/Maven URI but I am not sure how can an app deployed on CF be registered?

Appreciate your help. Please let me know if more details are needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the out-of-the-box apps that we ship, the relevant Maven repo configuration is already set within SCDF, so you can freely already deploy the `http` app, and SCDF would resolve and pull it from the Spring Maven repository and then deploy that application to CF.

However, if you're building custom apps, you can configure your internal/private Maven repositories in SCDF/Skipper and then register your apps using the coordinates from your internal repo.

If Maven is not a viable solution for you on CF, I have seen customers resolve artifacts from s3 buckets and persistent-volume services in CF.

Comment: I tried to run shell, skipper and SCDF from local. I can register app but can not deploy in CF. So not like option.  

I tried to run shell from my local and register source/sink via SCDF (& Skipper) deployed on CF. But apps are not started. Mainly as SCDF can not reach repo.spring.io. O/B via HTTP Proxy but I cant find a way to pass proxy details (host, port, username, pwd) to SCDF so it can use the proxy.

So at this point, looks like my immediate issue is more around http proxy. 2nd issue is using private maven repo (as we do not have one in my group).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should take time to read the docs to understand what is supported and how to go about configuring proxy properties. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-maven